# Save and load a game by using StreamWriter and ReadWriter (C#)

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm creating a small program which can save and load char array values. Then, I got stuck with two problems.

I have no idea how to make the program end after saving the data.
After loading the char array, it looks the game starts where I saved last time. However, when I put "#" on the place where is already marked, it is accepted. (It is supposed to display error message)

[image]

This is when I start new game.
It displays error message properly.
[image]

Here is class which includes streamWriter and streamReader.

```
    public class History
    {

        public char QUIT = 'Y';
        public char CONTINUE = 'N';
        public char inputGameContinue;
        

        public void WriteFile(char []arr)
        {

            FileStream sb = new FileStream("MyFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sb);
            WriteLine("If you want to save the data, enter" + QUIT +"| To continue, enter "+CONTINUE );
            inputGameContinue = char.Parse(ReadLine());
            if(inputGameContinue=='Y')
            {
                sw.Write(arr);
                WriteLine("The data is saved!");
                
                
            }
            
            sw.Close();
        }
        public void ReadFile()
        {

            string path = "MyFile.txt";
            WriteLine("New game? >> 1 | Load saved data? >>2 ");
            int command = int.Parse(ReadLine());
            if (command == 2)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
                {
                    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                    {
                        WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Class2

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.IO;

namespace createSample
{

    public class writeRead
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InputClass inputClass = new InputClass();
            ArrayValue arrayValue = new ArrayValue();
            History history = new History();

            WriteLine("Welcome to game!");
            WriteLine("");
            history.ReadFile();
            
                
            

            do
            {
                inputClass.inputNumber();
                while (true)
                {

                    if (arrayValue.arr[inputClass.input] == '#')
                    {
                        WriteLine("{0} already marked '#'. Try another.", inputClass.input);
                        inputClass.inputNumber();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        arrayValue.arr[inputClass.input] = '#';
                        arrayValue.printArray();
                        history.WriteFile(arrayValue.arr);
                        break;

                    }


                }
               


            }
            while (checkWhenFinish(arrayValue)!=1 );

            WriteLine("All letters are marked with '#'");
            Read();

        }
        public static int checkWhenFinish(ArrayValue a)
        {
            if(a.arr[0] != '0' && a.arr[1] != '1' && a.arr[2] != '2' && a.arr[3] != '3' && a.arr[4] != '4')
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
            
        }

    }

}
```

Class3

```
using System;
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using static System.Console;
using System.IO;

namespace createSample
{
    public class ArrayValue
    {
        public char []arr = { '0','1', '2', '3', '4' };
        
        public void printArray()
        {
            WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4]);
        }

    }

    
}
```

Class 4

```
using System;
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using static System.Console;
using System.IO;

namespace createSample
{
    public class InputClass
    {
        public int input;


        public void inputNumber()
        {

            while (true)
            {
                Write("Enter number ? (0 to 4)  >> ");
                if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out input))
                {
                    input = -1;
                }

                if (input == 0|| input == 1 || input == 2 || input == 3 || input == 4 )
                {

                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    WriteLine("Error! Try again!");
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: show us the code that checks for '#' and displays an error

Comment: @SlackGroverglow Thanks for your comment. It doesn't occur any technical error but I created the program to show error message to tell a user that if "#" is already stored in the char array, a user cannot choose. In this screenshot, I stored the char array values [0,1,#,3,4] to "Myfile". Then I loaded the file and the game displayed [0,1,#,3,4] . When I attempted choosing an index where "#" is already placed to make sure if an error message, "Invalid entry, try again!", is displayed, it just showed [0,1,#,3,4] again. I updated new screenshot to show you error message.

Comment: I understand that you don't get a technical error, but that your program is not working as intended and you want to fix that. Unfortunately the code sample you posted is not enough for me to help you with. You'll need to post the rest.

Comment: @SlackGroverglow I just posted other classes. I'll appreciate if you check them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you call `history.ReadFile()` it can read the file and display its contents, **but** it never updates `arrayValue.arr` so when the check is done later, `arrayValue.arr[inputClass.input]` is still `2`.

You might want to pass in `arrayValue` by reference to `ReadFile()` to have it updated:

```
history.ReadFile(ref arrayValue);
```

then in `History`

```
public void ReadFile(ref ArrayValue arrayValue)
{

   ...
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                var line = sr.ReadLine();
                WriteLine(line);
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayValue.arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    arrayValue.arr[i] = line[i];
                }
            }
   ...    
}
```